# Sonarqube evaluation: License error scanning a .Net Project?

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube

I downloaded SonarQube, set it up and installed the C# and VB plugins. I downloaded the MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner. I followed the instructions for [Analyzing with SonarQube for MSBuild](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) when I enter the MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end command I receive the following error:

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher
.java:91)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102
)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: com.A.vb.XYZ.A.A.A: Missing or bad plugin license. Please check logs.
```

Is licensing required for the C# plugin or the MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No license is required for the C# plugin or for SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild. But a license *is* required for the VB plugin. So uninstall that plugin and you should be good to go.

Alternately, you can [ask for a trial license](http://www.sonarsource.com/get-contact-sf/?Product__c=VB.net&Request_Type__c=Request%20an%20evaluation%20license%20key).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that with install older version of `sonar-scanner`:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner --version 4.10.0
```